# Urlredirect in MVC2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

In global.asax

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Test_Default", // Route name
            "test/{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{universe}",
            new { controller = "notfound", action = "error"}
        );
```

I have a controller: Home, containing an action: Index
Enter the url in browser: h**p://localhost:53235/test/home/index

Inside the index.aspx view in <body> tag: I want to link to the second route.

`<%=Html.RouteLink("Link", new { universe = "MyUniverse" })%>`

Shouldn't this generate a link to the second route in Global.asax? The generated url from the above is: h**p://localhost:53235/test/home/index?universe=MyUniverse. I can only get it to work, if I specify the name of the route: `<%=Html.RouteLink("Link", "default", new { universe = "MyUniverse" })%>`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered you need to use the route name if you want to generate a link to the second route. The first route will always be evaluated because even if the `universe` parameter doesn't exist in the route definition it is just passed as query string argument.